# How to Validate Form fields one by one with Parsley Js

Tags: javascript, jquery, parsley.js

I am trying to Validate a Form with Parsley JS But when I hit submit it's adding error class in all fields but I want that it should validate fields one by one.

So if the 5 inputs are required and I it submits without filling any of them so want to show error in the 1st input only. after that if i fill 1st input and left the other 4 then it should show error in the second input only. I am just using this code for my form now.

```
$('#formid').parsley( //nothing here for now );
```

Answer (score 0):

Set a specific priority to each input in the order you want them validated. Parsley will stop validation as soon as an error is detected at a given priority level.